# React WebApp <canvas> touch events

Tags: reactjs, canvas, touch, react-dom

Just a general question,

I know the most common approach to `<canvas>` tags in JavaScript is with the `onMouseDown`, `onMouseUp` and `onMouseMove` events when it comes to drawing. However I was wondering what is the corrent way to add touch events for mobile devices such as `onTouchStart`, `onTouchEnd` and `onTouchMove` without using traditional jQ such as `document.getElementById()`?

Thank you.